# Highlight.js not workng on Laravel 5.3 Target Page

Tags: laravel, highlight

I am developing a Blog with Laravel 5.3. In the Add Post Page, I use CKEDITOR with Code Snippet Plugin. In this area Everything is OK. Code added in the textarea field by plugin is also become highlighted.

In the Target Page I added:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.8.0/styles/default.min.css">
```

In the Header section of the page.

and

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.8.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();</script>
```

In the footer section of the page.

The page received the following html code from the Database.

```
&lt;p&gt;The place for Laravel Blade Template.&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;pre&gt;
&lt;code class=&quot;language-html&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;&lt;h1&gt;
This is a Header&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/code&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;

&lt;p&gt;&nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
```

which is showing like this.

```
<p>The place for Laravel Blade Template.</p> <pre> 
<code class="language-html"><div><h1>This is a Header</h1></div></code>
</pre> <p> </p>
```

So the code section is not highlighted.

How can I do that. What's my wrong? I need Help.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the **whole HTML code** is escaped, so it won't be interpreted by the browser.

What you want is that **only** the content between `<code class="language-html">...</code>` is escaped, so that the Browser renders the code container correctly and that highlight.js can hook into the DOM object.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5 to output non escaped HTML you must use `{!! !!}`

An example of this:

```
{!!$myDatabaseHtml!!}
```